# gRPC / C++ - How to store server streaming RPC's stream for later use

Tags: c++, grpc

What I want to achieve is to basically initiate messages from the server to the client. So basically my idea is I get the client to firstly trigger unary call which expect return of stream aka server streaming rpc.

I have this:

```proto
service Player {
    rpc PlayerSpawned(Empty) returns (stream CharacterShortData) {}
}
```

Here is my C++ code:

```cpp
namespace Vibranium{
    class PlayerService final : public Vibranium::Protobuffers::Player::Service {
    private:
        typedef ::grpc::ServerWriter< Vibranium::Protobuffers::CharacterShortData>* PlayerSpawnedEvent;
        PlayerSpawnedEvent _playerSpawnedWritter;
    public:
        grpc::Status PlayerSpawned(::grpc::ServerContext* context, const Vibranium::Protobuffers::Empty* request, ::grpc::ServerWriter<Vibranium::Protobuffers::CharacterShortData>* writer) override;
        void PlayerSpawned(Vibranium::Protobuffers::CharacterShortData const & character_short_data);
        static PlayerService* Instance();
    };
}
    
#define sAuthorativePlayerService PlayerService::Instance()
```

Here is my implementation and how I try to store the stream for later use:

```cpp
grpc::Status Vibranium::PlayerService::PlayerSpawned(::grpc::ServerContext *context, const Vibranium::Protobuffers::Empty *request,
                                              ::grpc::ServerWriter<Vibranium::Protobuffers::CharacterShortData> *writer)
{
    _playerSpawnedWritter = writer;
    return Status::OK;
}
```

```
void Vibranium::PlayerService::PlayerSpawned(const Vibranium::Protobuffers::CharacterShortData &character_short_data)
{
    _playerSpawnedWritter->Write(character_short_data);
}
```

However this does not work and I don't know why. Every time `return Status::OK;` deletes the pointer of `writer` which makes `_playerSpawnedWritter` invalid.

So every time I call `PlayerSpawned` I get a crash which is normal, because `_playerSpawnedWritter` is null.

So basically I can't store the stream. Is there any way I can keep the stream open and stored so later I can send additional messages specifically triggered from the server?

Comment: I have been wondering the exact same thing for a while now. As a hack for now I've put a
while(!context->IsCancelled()){}. Right before the return of the service function to keep it alive...

Comment: the client code calling the server code might be of great interest.
we can assume the client calls the rpc method but what does it do with the stream returned ? If it does not do antything with it, my guess is grpc will detect no one will never be able to accept the stream later on and it invalidates the server object

Answer (score 1):

you need to store  grpc::ServerWriterVibranium::Protobuffers::CharacterShortData  in map like std::unordered_map

```
namespace Vibranium {
    class PlayerService final : public Vibranium::Protobuffers::Player::Service {
    private:
        std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<grpc::ServerWriter<Vibranium::Protobuffers::CharacterShortData>>> _clientWriters;

    public:
        grpc::Status PlayerSpawned(::grpc::ServerContext* context, const Vibranium::Protobuffers::Empty* request,
                                   grpc::ServerWriter<Vibranium::Protobuffers::CharacterShortData>* writer) override;
        void SendCharacterDataToClient(const std::string& clientId, const Vibranium::Protobuffers::CharacterShortData& characterData);
        
         void PlayerSpawned(Vibranium::Protobuffers::CharacterShortData const & character_short_data);

         static PlayerService* Instance();
    };
}
```

then The _clientWriters map is used to store the your active client connections and their  ServerWriter objects.

```
grpc::Status Vibranium::PlayerService::PlayerSpawned(::grpc::ServerContext* context, const Vibranium::Protobuffers::Empty* request,
                                                    grpc::ServerWriter<Vibranium::Protobuffers::CharacterShortData>* writer)
{
    // Store the writer in the client writers map
    _clientWriters[context->peer()] = std::make_unique<grpc::ServerWriter<Vibranium::Protobuffers::CharacterShortData>>(writer);

    

    return Status::OK;
}
```

and method  void Vibranium::PlayerService::PlayerSpawned(const Vibranium::Protobuffers::CharacterShortData &character_short_data)

I have renamed to WriteToClient

```
void Vibranium::PlayerService::WriteToClient(const std::string& clientId, const Vibranium::Protobuffers::CharacterShortData& characterData)
{
    auto it = _clientWriters.find(clientId);
    if (it != _clientWriters.end()) {
        // Asynchronously write to the stored writer
        it->second->Write(characterData);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a correct answer. How is this different from the original proposed solution in the question? Even if you store the `writer` pointer in a map instead of a field the writer will still get deleted once you return `Status::OK`? Is this answer generated by ChatGPT?