# Project .net framework to .net 6 core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, .net-6.0

I'm facing an issue in my C# project where I'm getting the following error message:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Priority
```

> Error CS1705  Assembly 'Application' with identity 'Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions' with identity 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'  AdditionnalDataManagerAPI   C:\Users\ala.bachhamba\source\repos\AdditionnalDataManagerAPI\CSc

I'm using the 'AdditionnalDataManagerAPI' project, and it seems to be related to a version conflict with 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions'. How can I resolve this error and make sure the project uses the correct version of the assembly?

I checked my project's references to ensure that 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions' is correctly referenced.
I attempted to update the reference to 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions' to the latest version, but it didn't resolve the issue.
I searched online for solutions and documentation related to 'CS1705 Error' and version conflicts but couldn't find a solution that worked for my specific case.

Comment: It's really unclear how your title relates to your question. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: The errors are about mixed up NuGet packages, not a migration. It's quite possible that a manual migration caused the package mixup though. .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6, not a newer version of .NET Framework. If you want to migrate, it's safer to use the migration assistant instead of changing `csproj` by hand

Comment: The error shows a *severe* mixup too. You mention .NET 6 but the error shows you use v7 and v8 packages. Please post the `csproj` files for all the projects involved. If you use Visual Studio, use [ Manage NuGet Packages for Solution.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#manage-packages-for-the-solution) and ensure all packages use the same version through the [Consolidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#consolidate-tab) tab.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Potential issue might be referenced project is using preview version of package version `8.0.0-*` and other project is referencing stable version `7.0.0` as latest package. Updating to preview packages should resolve the issue.

[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions - Version History](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/#versions-body-tab)

**INITIAL RESPONSE:**

You can enable auto binding redirect or add/edit redirect in csproj file.

Enabling auto binding redirect:

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

Add or edit binding redirect:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions"
    publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60"
    culture="en-us" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

More info:

[Redirecting assembly versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions)

Comment: Or ideally, given the title, don't use assembly binding redirects... since using the modern SDK-style projects, I haven't had any problems with assembly bindings...

Comment: Well, if you are referencing preview version in one library and stable version in another it doesn't work that well. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I would say that's not so much about preview vs not preview as "two different major versions". That would be a broken configuration (in terms of SemVer) even if both were stable.

Comment: Yes, but these Microsoft packages are versioned based on framework version rather to indicate breaking changes, even tho there might be some.

Comment: Also it seems to me it is preview vs not preview version as preview versions are not installed/used automatically. So, what might work without assembly binding in modern SDK-style projects will be broken, unless you explicitly enable previews. I didn't try it, but it seems logical. We will see once someone resolves it.

Comment: thnks +1 for all

Answer (score -2):

While migrating  from .NET framework to .NET 6 core,  you have to keep following thing in mind

- reference library in your project is compliant to which .NET standard/netstandard ( .NET standard 1.x, or 2.0 or 2.1 )?
- By default .NET 6.0 core set to net standard 2.1 and your .net framework may be   net standard 2.0 or earlier one

Hence if you re-target a project to a different version of .NET, your references may not resolve properly in some cases. Explicit fully qualified references to assemblies often cause this issue, but you can resolve it by removing the references that don't resolve and then adding them back to the project.

For more details follow below article and remove your reference (in your case "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions") and then reference again.

[Framework Retargeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/project-build/troubleshooting-dotnet-framework-targeting-errors#you-re-target-a-project-to-a-different-version-of-net-and-references-arent-resolved)

Comment: This isn't related to the question, contains serious errors (no, .NET Core 6 isn't set to .NET Standard 2.1) and frankly, reads like a ChatGPT answer that didn't understand the question.

Comment: this is not a ChatGPT,  you can refer link of microsoft document where it is explaining more in details about  versioning issue

Comment: That link doesn't refer to the question's case at all. And this answer has serious errors. The cross-platform target in .NET 6 is .NET 6 itself. Since .NET 5 there's no .NET Standard any more, so `By default .NET 6.0 core set to net standard 2.1` is wrong. Platform-specific targets are built on top of .NET 6 so there's no need for .NET Standard 6. This is explained in [The future of .NET Standard](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-future-of-net-standard/)

Comment: As for the question's problem, it's caused because different projects use v7 and v8 versions of the `Microsoft.Extensions.*` packages. This wasn't caused by migration or multitargeting

Comment: read the title of question .  it indicate that they are going from .net framework to .net 6 core

Comment: I read the title *and* the question itself, which complains about mixing up v7 and v8 of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions`. That's why the answer isn't relevant. Migration alone wouldn't cause this, but careless removing/adding or upgrading to the latest *preview* would.

Comment: migration does this  as Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions itself has dependency in .net 4.6  but not in .net 6. core  please refer dependency chart  for below    NuGet package 

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/7.0.0#dependencies-body-tab

Comment: I have reference project, it returned this a bug, thanks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've had similar experiences with this user using ChatGPT generated answers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72129836/grpc-c-how-to-store-server-streaming-rpcs-stream-for-later-use/76937759#comment135655906_76937759